# checking element present in an array using sql

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table with 3 columns: col1,col2,col3. Column3 is an array.

```
col3
[abc,def,xyz]
[abc,qwe,pou]
[]
[qwe,xyz]
[qwe,pou]
```

I have to write a sql query where i get col1, col2 and instead of col3, i have check whether it has value in('abc','xyz'). If it has these values then new_col = 1 else 0.

So the new_col looks like this:

```
new_col
1
1
0
1
0
```

i am looking for something like

```
select col1,col2, case when col3 in('xyz','abc')then 1 else 0 end as new_col from table
```

But this gives me an error saying "IN value and list items must have same type:array(varchar)"

Comment: Since some SQL database systems don't even *have* an array type, it would really help if you added a specific tag for your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me.

```
  select col1, col2,case when cardinality(filter(col3, x->x in( 'abc', 'xyz')))>0 then 1 else 0 end as new_col from <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Amazona Athena engine version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference-0003.html) you should be able to use [`any_match` from array functions](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match):

```sql
with dataset(arr) as(
values (array ['abc','def','xyz']),
    (array ['abc','qwe','pou']),
    (array []),
    (array ['qwe','xyz']),
    (array ['qwe','pou'])
)

select if(any_match(arr, e -> e in ( 'abc', 'xyz')), 1, 0)
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

For earlier version you can use `array_intersect`:

```sql
select if(cardinality(array_intersect(arr, array['abc', 'xyz'])) > 0, 1, 0)
from dataset;
```